# My code crashes when calling the F77_NAME() function from the lapack library

Tags: c, r, lapack

I'm trying to call the `F77_NAME(dgeqrf)` function from lapack lib but the program crashes.

What do you think it is wrong?

```
#include <R.h>
#include <R_ext/BLAS.h>
#include <R_ext/Lapack.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double* getcopy(int* nrow, int* ncol, double* a) {
  double* copy = malloc(*nrow * *ncol * sizeof(double));
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < *nrow * *ncol; i++) {
    copy[i] = a[i];
  }
  return copy;
}

int main() {
  int m = 3, n = 3;
  double a[] = {12, -51, 4, 6, 167, -68, -4, 24, -41};
  double* acopy = getcopy(&m, &n, a);

  double tau[3];
  int info = 0;
  int i;

  int one = 1;
  double* work = malloc(max(&one, &m) * sizeof(double));
  int lwork = 0;
  int lda = max(&m, &n);

  F77_NAME(dgeqrf)(&m, &n, acopy, &m, tau, work, &lwork, &info);

  for (i = 0; i < m * n; i++) printf("%f", acopy[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do `int lwork = max(&one, &m)` so that LAPACK knows the size of the workspace ? Otherwise this seems okay, you definitely should use a debugger to see which line makes the program crash.

Comment: Instead of a debugger, it might suffice to use several well-placed `printf()` statements.

Comment: :)) i can't believe it, it worked, it needed the max(&one,&m) ... need to be more carefully and sleep after 10 hours of coding

Answer (score 0):

From dgeqrf.f source code:

```
*  LWORK   (input) INTEGER
*          The dimension of the array WORK.  LWORK >= max(1,N).
*          For optimum performance LWORK >= N*NB, where NB is
*          the optimal blocksize.
*
*          If LWORK = -1, then a workspace query is assumed; the routine
*          only calculates the optimal size of the WORK array, returns
*          this value as the first entry of the WORK array, and no error
*          message related to LWORK is issued by XERBLA.
```

So if you want an optimal run you first need to call the function with 'lwork' set to -1 to get the optimal size of 'work'.